# How can i do this action?

Tags: gdscript

What do I have to add to this code so that when pressing the shift key the animation "run" is reproduced and the speed is multiplied by 1.5

```
`extends CharacterBody2D


var speed := 120
var direccion := 0.0 
var jump := 250
var gravity := 9

@onready var anim := $AnimationPlayer
@warning_ignore("unused_parameter")
func _physics_process(delta):
    direccion = Input.get_axis("ui_left","ui_right")
    velocity.x = direccion * speed
    
    if direccion != 0.0:
        anim.play("walk")
    else:
        anim.play("idle")
    if is_on_floor() and Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_accept"):
        velocity.y -= jump
        
    if !is_on_floor():
        velocity.y += gravity
    
    
    move_and_slide()`
```

I don't now what to do

Answer (score 0):

You can check for specific keys. In the spirit of transparency, I'm going to tell you it is with `Input.is_key_pressed(KEY_SHIFT)`. But I'm going to advice against it. Instead...

Go to Project Settings, on the Input Map tab define a custom action "run" and map it to Shift. *The day you want to change it, you change it there. For example if you want to add game controller support. Also if in the future you want to provide the user the option to configure them by themselves, it will be easier. OK? OK.*

Now that you have the action defined you can use `Input.is_action_pressed("run")`.

In fact, you are using the `ui_*` actions, which is what a tutorial will do to get you writing code quickly and not have to tell you to define Input Maps. Yet, yet those are for UI (`Control`s), so you might want to define custom ones to replace those too.

---

The rest you can figure out:

- When the run action is pressed, you multiply the `speed` by some `run_factor` which you say would to be `1.5`.
- And when the run action is pressed, instead of using the `"walk"` animation you use the `"run"` animation.

Nothing that an `if` or two can't do.

---

For you to ponder: do you want the animation to change to `"run"` based on the `"run"` action, or based on the speed? Similarly, will there be `"jump"` or `"fall"` animations?

As it turns out, removing a concern (in this case handling animations) makes the code simpler:

```
var run_speed_factor := 1.5

func _physics_process(_delta:float) -> void:
    direccion = Input.get_axis("move_left", "move_right")
    velocity.x = direccion * speed
    if Input.is_action_pressed("run"):
        velocity.x *= run_speed_factor

    if is_on_floor():
        velocity.y += gravity
    elif Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump"):
        velocity.y -= jump
    
    move_and_slide()
```

Now, if the animations do not depend on the input, but on the state, you can do them separately, for example:

```
func _process(_delta:float) -> void:
    if is_zero_aprox(velocity.y):
        if is_zero_aprox(velocity.x):
            anim.play("idle")
        elif absf(velocity.x) > speed:
            anim.play("run")
        else:
            anim.play("walk")
    elif velocity.y > 0.0:
        anim.play("fall")
    else:
        anim.play("jump")
```